# Actually executing a program from a python script

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess

I've been messing around with this for over an hour, and I've looked at several questions here on Stack Overflow. I'm trying to actually execute a program, not wrap it with a python python process for an output.

I have a code in place to monitor a daemon and if, for whatever reason, it closes I want to reopen it. The only thing I've found that does this is the os.startfile. My problem is I can't add any command line arguments to os.startfile.

I've read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/os.html#os.startfile) on os.startfile and I'm having a hard time understanding it. In the docs it is talking about open start arguments, etc. but in the code example of PyCharm it is only showing two arguments for the function, path, and operation
[image]

and this ...

```py
from sys import argv
from os import startfile

if len(argv) == 1:
    startfile(r'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k python.exe os_startfile.py process', operation = 'open')
else:
    for index, enum in enumerate(argv):
        print(index, enum)
exit()
```

is generating the error ...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\phpjunkie\Python\Scripts\testing\os_startfile.py", line 5, in <module>
    startfile(r'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k python.exe os_startfile.py process', operation = 'open')
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /k python.exe os_startfile.py process'
```

Comment: The title of the question doesn't seem related.  To open a file in Python, ("actually open" it, that is!), you can use `open`.

Comment: I change the name of the title. It is misleading. I know that I can use open to "open" a file for reading and writing content to the file. What I was wanting to do was actually execute a file. To launch another program.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs at [docs.python.org/3.11/library/os.html#os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/os.html#os.startfile) it shows more arguments then what PyCharm is showing in it's documentation popup. I was able to get this working with the following code

```py
from sys import argv
from os import startfile

if len(argv) == 1:
    startfile(filepath = r'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe ', operation = 'open', arguments = '/k python.exe os_startfile.py process')
else:
    for index, enum in enumerate(argv):
        print(index, enum)
exit()
```

PyCharm is showing `filepath` and `arguments` as an `Unexpected argument` warnings.

PyCharm is also reporting `Parameter "path" unfilled`

Answer (score -1):

whereas @phpjunkie's answer solves your issue, you should have a look at subprocess.run

Comment: I have and it did the same thing. I'm using python 3.11.7 and all it id was wrap the the process and not actually open the program. The whole point of the code below was to get the actual terminal window. subprocess.run didn't do it.